# Parallel sieve of Eratosthenes - Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wanted to write sieve of Eratosthenes which will work using specific number of threads. I figured out, that it will work in following way:
For 2 threads up to 17. 
Thread-1 takes 2, and starts to remove multiple of 2 from List. Parallel Thread-2 takes 3 and does the same. After that Thread-1 takes 5( because there is no 4 in List) and Thread-2 takes 7 and so on until they reach end.
I wrote following piece of code:

```
private List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public synchronized void run(){
    while(array.size() > 0){
        Integer tmp = array.get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++){
            if( (array.get(i).intValue() % tmp.intValue()) == 0)
                array.remove(i);
        }
        results.add(array.get(0));
        array.remove(0);
    }
}

public void setArray(int x){
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        array.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
}
public void printArray(){
    for(Integer i: results){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This code works, but I added time measurement "tool" to my main class:

```
ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask();
task.setArray(5000);
Long beg = new Date().getTime();
for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
    new Thread(task).start();
}
Long sleep = 1000L;
Thread.sleep(sleep);// I am sleeping main thread to wait until other Threads are done
task.printArray();
System.out.println("Time is "+(new Date().getTime()-beg-sleep));
```

The problem is that running this with 2 threads is slower than running with 1 thread, and 3 threads are slower than 2 threads. Could anyone explain me, why?

**EDIT:**

There is one important thing about that. I don't need it to be done as fast as it can be. I need it working on Threads for one reason. My Teacher wants to compare runtimes of running same program with 1, 2 .. n threads. Results should look like in [this](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plik%3aParallelization_graph.jpg) graph.

**EDIT2:**

I have rewritten code to following

```
private HashMap<Integer,Boolean> array = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
private int counter = 1;
private int x;
public void run(){
    while(counter < x-1){
        do{
            counter++;
        }
        while( array.get(counter));
        int tmp = counter;
        for(int i = tmp; i < array.size(); i+=tmp){
            if( i!= tmp)
                array.put(i,true);
        }
        try{
        Thread.sleep(0L, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
}

public void setArray(int x){
    this.x = x;
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        array.put(i, false);
}
public void printArray(){

    for(int i = 2; i < array.size();i++){
        if( !array.get(i))
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

Now it uses HashMap and this is how it works:

1. Fill HashMap with keys from 2 to n and false values.
2. New thread goes into while loop which is based on `counter` variable. `Counter` represents current key.
3. Increment counter on the begging so new threads doesn't operate on `counter` of earlier started thread.
4. Put `counter` value into temporary variable `tmp` so we can work even when another thread increment `counter`
5. Iterate through the HashMap by incrementing `i` with `tmp` ( it is actually jumping on the multiplies of i) and set their values to `true`.
6. All keys which has `true` value are ignored in print method. Also `counter` skips them when incremented.

The problem is that it still works **slower** with more threads. What's wrong now?

Comment: Your run method is synchronized so only 1 thread may run at a time.

Comment: if `run` is the actual `run` method of your `ThreadTask`, then your two threads essentially work sequentially because the method is synchronized, preventing the threads to work in parallel (which is the point of using threads!).

Comment: I think there's a problem... You say that Thread-1 takes 5 because there's no 4 in the list.  That works with only two threads, because Thread-1 already deleted the 4.  But what if there are three threads?  How would Thread-3 know not to take 4, if it's not certain that Thread-1 already got it?  I guess it will still work if Thread-3 starts with 4, but it will be doing redundant work.  Or else some really tricky synchronization has to be done to avoid this kind of race condition.  I'm skeptical that this is a suitable algorithm for parallel threads.

Comment: Even if you get it to work by sharing the work across threads, it will never be very fast if you are accessing the same structure, whether it be an array or other.  The proper approach to multi-processing is to divide the sieve into pages of a reasonable size and assign one thread to each page, merging the results using a foreground thread.  This is what I did in C# [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18885065/549617) to great effectiveness (segmented sieves are much more memory access efficient as well).  This algorithm can easily be translated to Java and will run at about the same speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is simpler than I first thought.  All your threads are doing the same thing so each thread does more work.  To make a multi-threaded program work faster you have to divide up the work, which has to be performed concurrently.

---

When you have one thread accessing a data structure, it can be in the fastest cache of one core, use multiple threads and they need to co-ordinate their actions and since most of the work is updating the data structure, a lot of time is lost as overhead.  This is the case even though your data structure is not thread safe and is likely to have a corrupted result.

BTW updating an ArrayList is very expensive and using a collection objects is also an overhead.

You will get a much faster result using a BitSet and just one thread.

```
public class BitSetSieveMain {
    private final BitSet set;
    private final int size;

    public BitSetSieveMain(int x) {
        size = x + 1;
        set = new BitSet(size);
        set.flip(2, size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            BitSetSieveMain bitSetSieveMain = new BitSetSieveMain(5000);
            bitSetSieveMain.sieve();
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.println(time / 1000 + " micro-seconds to perform " + bitSetSieveMain);
        }
    }

    public void sieve() {
        int i = 2;
        do {
            for (int j = i*2; j < size; j += i)
                set.clear(j);
            i = set.nextSetBit(i+1);
        } while (i > 0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return set.toString();
    }
}
```

finally prints

87 micro-seconds to perform {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999}

Comment: Your conclusions become increasingly obscure! ;-)